# FAILED to Install PDO through WHM

Tags: php, linux, pdo, centos6, whm

I had a hard time trying to install oauth on php 5.6, but could easily install it on php 7.0, so I changed the php version to 7. Great! But then PDO is not working anymore.

I tried to install it using the WHM (“PHP Pecl” Installer) and it fails.

Server info: CENTOS 6.8 x86_64 kvm – server  WHM 60.0 (build 28)

Thanks!

PDO (1.0.3)

```
WARNING: "pecl/PDO" is deprecated in favor of "channel://http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/pdo//ext/PDO"
downloading PDO-1.0.3.tgz ...
Starting to download PDO-1.0.3.tgz (52,613 bytes)
.............done: 52,613 bytes
12 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20151012
Zend Module Api No:      20151012
Zend Extension Api No:   320151012
building in /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/pear-build-rootB7oQlL/PDO-1.0.3
running: /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/configure --with-php-config=/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/bin/php-config
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/include/php -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/include/php/main -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/include/php/Zend -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/include/php/ext -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/lib64/php/modules
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether to enable PDO support... yes, shared
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1966080
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ar... ar
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing libtool commands
running: make
/bin/sh /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/pear-build-rootB7oQlL/PDO-1.0.3/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/pear-build-rootB7oQlL/PDO-1.0.3/include -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/pear-build-rootB7oQlL/PDO-1.0.3/main -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/include/php -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/include/php/main -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/include/php/Zend -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/include/php/ext -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/pdo.c -o pdo.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/pear-build-rootB7oQlL/PDO-1.0.3/include -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/pear-build-rootB7oQlL/PDO-1.0.3/main -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/include/php -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/include/php/main -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/include/php/Zend -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/include/php/ext -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/pdo.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/pdo.o
In file included from /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/pdo.c:32:
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/php_pdo_driver.h: In function 'pdo_attr_lval':
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/php_pdo_driver.h:191: error: too many arguments to function 'zend_hash_index_find'
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/php_pdo_driver.h:192: warning: passing argument 1 of 'zval_get_type' from incompatible pointer type
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_types.h:326: note: expected 'const struct zval *' but argument is of type 'struct zval **'
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/php_pdo_driver.h:192: warning: passing argument 1 of 'convert_to_long' from incompatible pointer type
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_operators.h:244: note: expected 'struct zval *' but argument is of type 'struct zval **'
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/php_pdo_driver.h: In function 'pdo_attr_strval':
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/php_pdo_driver.h:201: error: too many arguments to function 'zend_hash_index_find'
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/php_pdo_driver.h:202: warning: passing argument 1 of 'zval_get_type' from incompatible pointer type
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_types.h:326: note: expected 'const struct zval *' but argument is of type 'struct zval **'
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/php_pdo_driver.h:202: warning: passing argument 1 of 'zval_get_type' from incompatible pointer type
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_types.h:326: note: expected 'const struct zval *' but argument is of type 'struct zval **'
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/php_pdo_driver.h:202: warning: passing argument 1 of '_convert_to_string' from incompatible pointer type
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_operators.h:243: note: expected 'struct zval *' but argument is of type 'struct zval **'
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/php_pdo_driver.h:203: warning: passing argument 1 of '_estrndup' makes pointer from integer without a cast
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_alloc.h:85: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'int'
In file included from /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/pdo.c:33:
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/php_pdo_int.h: At top level:
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/php_pdo_int.h:34: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'pdo_dbh_new'
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/php_pdo_int.h:39: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'pdo_dbstmt_new'
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/php_pdo_int.h:48: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'pdo_row_new'
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/pdo.c: In function 'php_pdo_get_exception_base':
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/pdo.c:68: warning: passing argument 2 of 'zend_hash_find' from incompatible pointer type
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_hash.h:154: note: expected 'struct zend_string *' but argument is of type 'char *'
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/pdo.c:68: error: too many arguments to function 'zend_hash_find'
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/pdo.c: In function 'zif_pdo_drivers':
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/pdo.c:96: warning: passing argument 2 of 'zend_hash_get_current_data_ex' from incompatible pointer type
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_hash.h:171: note: expected 'HashPosition *' but argument is of type 'void **'
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/pdo.c:96: error: too many arguments to function 'zend_hash_get_current_data_ex'
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/pdo.c:97: error: too many arguments to function 'add_next_index_stringl'
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/pdo.c: In function 'php_pdo_register_driver':
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/pdo.c:165: warning: passing argument 2 of 'zend_hash_exists' from incompatible pointer type
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_hash.h:159: note: expected 'struct zend_string *' but argument is of type 'char *'
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/pdo.c:165: error: too many arguments to function 'zend_hash_exists'
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/pdo.c:171:41: error: macro "zend_hash_add" passed 6 arguments, but takes just 3
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/pdo.c:170: error: 'zend_hash_add' undeclared (first use in this function)
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/pdo.c:170: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/pdo.c:170: error: for each function it appears in.)
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/pdo.c: In function 'php_pdo_unregister_driver':
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/pdo.c:176: warning: passing argument 2 of 'zend_hash_exists' from incompatible pointer type
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_hash.h:159: note: expected 'struct zend_string *' but argument is of type 'char *'
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/pdo.c:176: error: too many arguments to function 'zend_hash_exists'
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/pdo.c:180: warning: passing argument 2 of 'zend_hash_del' from incompatible pointer type
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_hash.h:146: note: expected 'struct zend_string *' but argument is of type 'char *'
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/pdo.c:180: error: too many arguments to function 'zend_hash_del'
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/pdo.c: In function 'pdo_find_driver':
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/pdo.c:187: warning: passing argument 2 of 'zend_hash_find' from incompatible pointer type
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_hash.h:154: note: expected 'struct zend_string *' but argument is of type 'char *'
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/pdo.c:187: error: too many arguments to function 'zend_hash_find'
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/pdo.c: In function 'zm_startup_pdo':
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/pdo.c:323: error: too many arguments to function 'zend_register_internal_class_ex'
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/pdo.c: In function 'zm_info_pdo':
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/pdo.c:371: warning: passing argument 2 of 'zend_hash_get_current_data_ex' from incompatible pointer type
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_hash.h:171: note: expected 'HashPosition *' but argument is of type 'void **'
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/PDO/pdo.c:371: error: too many arguments to function 'zend_hash_get_current_data_ex'
make: *** [pdo.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Comment: I have the same problem, using the easy apache 4 manager it seems like pdo is installed for my php7.2 but my php scripts returns that pdo is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

If you have EasyApache4 there is no need to compile the PDO module. You can install it via EasyApache. Select current profile and check the pdo module for your current php version. You can select PDO for all php version 5.x, 5.6.x 7.x

If you have EasyApache3 you can re-compile apache + php using EasyApache section in WHM. Then on php modules, where you can customize your php install you can select the PDO extension/module for php. EasyApache will build php (the version you have selected) and also all the modules that you have selected to be enabled on your EasyApache Profile